# Correct prototype chain for Function

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

What is the correct output (meaning correct by the ECMA standard) of the following program?

```
function nl(x) { document.write(x + "<br>"); }
nl(Function.prototype);
nl(Function.prototype.prototype);
nl(Function.prototype.prototype == Object.prototype);
nl(Function.prototype.prototype.prototype);
```

Chrome and IE6 agree in saying:

```
function Empty() {}
null for Chrome / undefined for IE6
false
```

and then crashing.

Mozilla outputs:

```
function () { }
[object Object]
false
undefined
```

Are either of these correct? It seems that the Mozilla one does better, but that the best output is

```
function () { }
[object Object]
true
undefined
```

Comment: See also this link: [link](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es5-discuss/2009-May/002541.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're doing here isn't really walking the prototype chain - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383201/relation-between-prototype-and-prototype-in-javascript) might help you understand what is actually going on. I didn't bother to check the ECMA spec, but here is my take on the issue:

- **Function** is the constructor of function objects
- **Function.prototype** is the prototype from which all function objects inherit - it might contain properties like *call* and *apply* which are common to all *Function* instances; the implementations you checked were consistent in that it is implemented as a function object itself (as **some** pointed out, the ECMA specification requires this)
- **Function.prototype.prototype** does't really make much sense, but as **Function.prototype** is implemented as a function object (which could possibly be used as a constructor), it should at least exists; objects which are created using **Function.prototype** as constructor would inherit its properties - but as there should be no reason to do something insane like this, setting it to *null*, *undefined* or an empty object is reasonable
- **Function.prototype.prototype.prototype** will in all likelyhood be *undefined*: as we have seen before, **Function.prototype.prototype** should be something without properties (*null*, *undefined* or an empty object) and definetely not a function object; therefore, its *prototype* property should be *undefined* or might even throw an error when trying to be accessed

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: It's one step less actually:
`> Function.prototype() - undefined`
`> new Function.prototype() - Error 'Function.prototype' is not a constructor`
`> Function.prototype.prototype - undefined`

Answer (score 12):

**Function.prototype**

From [ECMAScript Language
Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

> **15.3.3.1 Function.prototype**
>
> The initial value of Function.prototype is
>   the Function prototype object (section
>   15.3.4).
>
> **15.3.4 Properties of the Function Prototype Object**
>
> The Function
>   prototype object is itself a Function
>   object (its [[Class]] is "Function")
>   that, when invoked, accepts any
>   arguments and returns undefined. The
>   value of the internal [[Prototype]]
>   property of the Function prototype
>   object is the Object prototype object
>   (section 15.3.2.1).
>
> It is a function with an “empty body”;
>   if it is invoked, it merely returns
>   undefined. The Function prototype
>   object does not have a valueOf
>   property of its own; however, it
>   inherits the valueOf property from the
>   Object prototype Object.

I get this output:

- **Opera:** function () { [native code] }
- **Chrome:** function Empty() {}
- **IE7:** function prototype() {    [native code]}
- **FF3:** function () { }

Chrome and IE7 has named their functions, Opera and IE7 tells you that it will not reveal the implementation. They all agree on this:

```
nl(typeof Function.prototype); //function
```

Compare this to:

```
nl(typeof Object.prototype); //object
nl(typeof Array.prototype); //object
nl(typeof String.prototype); // object
```

**Function.prototype.prototype**

I get **undefined** from Opera and IE7, **null** from Chrome and **[object Object]** from FF3. Who is right? Since *"The Function prototype object is itself a Function object"* shouldn't it be a circular reference to itself? To avoid the circular reference they have chosen different ways. I don't know if there is a standard for that or if it is up to the implementation, but I think an Object is right. Btw, here you see the difference between the internal [[prototype]] and the public prototype in action, like you asked in an earlier question!

**Function.prototype.prototype == Object.prototype**

This is false because it isn't the same object. See above.

**Function.prototype.prototype.prototype**

Only FF will give you an answer because of their implementation of Function.prototype.prototype returns an Object.

I agree that your proposed output looks more logic.

They do agree on this:

```
nl(Object.prototype); // [object Object]
nl(Object.prototype.prototype); // undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question directly: Mozilla is right. Not only because Brendan Eich works for Mozilla, but because this is the only right way to do it. Let's go over details:

- Every constructor is a function.
- Every function has `prototype` property to be used to construct objects.
- The prototype is an object (a dictionary). Individual objects delegate methods/properties to their respective prototypes.
- In the case of a function, the prototype object is special — it implements function-specific methods and properties. The type/class of this object is not defined, and not directly available.
- This prototype object cannot be `Object` nor `Object.prototype`.

Let me elaborate on the last statement. If it is false, we can recreate function in the user code like that:

```
// we re-creating the function!

// our function constructor
var Fun = function(){ /*...*/ };

// let's chain the prototype
Fun.prototype = new Object();

// do we have a function now? let's fund out
var fun = new Fun();
console.log(fun.length);  // undefined
fun.call(null);           // fail
fun.apply({}, [1, 2, 3]); // fail
// nope
```

We can observe that `new Object()` doesn't define new methods nor properties and can try using `Object.prototype` directly with the same result.

Summary: the prototype of the function is not `Object` nor `Object.prototype`. It is some very special object. This is one more reason why we cannot re-create a function in the user code.

EDIT: for more details on prototypes look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383201/relation-between-prototype-and-prototype-in-javascript#383478).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why would the result of the Fun() constructor return something that supported the call() or apply() methods? Those methods belong to functions but what's returned from the constructor is just a plain old object?

Comment: If you set the prototype to be a function object, then the object created by the constructor would have those properties: 
function Moo() { }
Moo.prototype = function() { };
var moo1 = new Moo();
alert(moo1.apply)

Comment: This doesn't work: var moo1 = new ...; moo1(1, "2", true); --- having methods named apply and call doesn't help with operators. JS doesn't allow to define operators and operations, and there is no legal way to inherit/delegate them. I used apply/call as examples that "may" work, but don't.

Comment: It is easy to dispel the confusion and test your hypothesis --- just run my example and see if it works for you. Then mod it to fit your hypothesis and run again. See where it works (if any). Report back. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is kind of old, but I've been searching the net for information on this subject and figured I'd post what I found. The prototype property is for constructor functions. It allows you to assign the prototype object of objects you will create with the new keyword.

Every object in JavaScript has a prototype object, but many implementations don't give you direct access to it or allow you to set it after object creation. In FireFox, you can access this object via the "`__proto__`" property.

Below I have a version of your code using the "`__proto__`" property. The section on the Function prototype chain matches what you thought it should have been.

```
function nl(z) { document.write(z + "<br>"); }

x = {};

nl(x["__proto__"]);
nl(x["__proto__"] === Object.prototype);

nl("");

nl(nl.prototype.constructor);
nl(nl["__proto__"].constructor);
nl(nl["__proto__"] === nl.prototype);

nl("");

nl(nl["__proto__"]);
nl(nl["__proto__"] === Function.prototype);
nl(nl["__proto__"]["__proto__"] === Object.prototype);
nl(nl["__proto__"]["__proto__"]["__proto__"]);

nl("");

nl(Function["__proto__"]);
nl(Function["__proto__"]["__proto__"]);
nl(Function["__proto__"]["__proto__"] === Object.prototype);
nl(Function["__proto__"]["__proto__"]["__proto__"]);
```

Output in FireFox is:

```
[object Object]
true

function nl(z) { document.write(z + "
"); }
function Function() { [native code] }
false

function () { }
true
true
null

function () { }
[object Object]
true
null
```