# Relation between [[Prototype]] and prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecma262

From http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html :

> Note: ECMAScript defines an internal [[prototype]] property of the internal Object type. This property is not directly accessible with scripts, but it is the chain of objects referred to with the internal [[prototype]] property that is used in property accessor resolution; the object's prototype chain. A public prototype property exists to allow the assignment, definition and manipulation of prototypes in association with the internal [[prototype]] property. **The details of the relationship between to two are described in ECMA 262 (3rd edition) and are beyond the scope of this discussion.**

What are the details of the relationship between the two? I've browsed through ECMA 262 and all I've read there is stuff like:

> The constructor’s associated prototype can be referenced by the program expression constructor.prototype,
>
> Native ECMAScript objects have an internal property called [[Prototype]]. The value of this property is either null or an object and is used for implementing inheritance.
>
> Every built-in function and every built-in constructor has the Function prototype object, which is the initial value of the expression Function.prototype
>
> Every built-in prototype object has the Object prototype object, which is the initial value of the expression
> Object.prototype (15.3.2.1), as the value of its internal [[Prototype]] property, except the Object
> prototype object itself.

From this all I gather is that the [[Prototype]] property is equivalent to the `prototype` property for pretty much any object. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I believe you are right in most cases.

Every object has a hidden `[[Prototype]]` property, which is used for inheritance. Functions additionally have a public `prototype` property, which is used only when the function is used as constructor: When an object is constructed using `new`, the `[[Prototype]]` property of the new object is set to the `prototype` property of the function that was used as constructor.

E.g.

```
function C() {}
C.prototype = P1;  
var obj = new C();  // obj.[[Prototype]] is now P1.
```

You can get the `[[Prototype]]` property using `Object.getPrototypeOf(<obj>)`. (This method is specified in ECMAScript 5. Older versions of JavaScript does not have any standard way of reading `[[Prototype]]`).

You can *usually* get to the prototype through the constructor, e.g.:

```
obj.constructor.prototype == Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)
```

But this is not always the case, since the prototype property of the constructor function can be reassigned, but the `[[Prototype]]` of an object cannot be reassigned after the object is created. So if you do:

```
C.prototype = P2;
```

then

```
obj.constructor.prototype != Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)
```

Because the prototype of `C` is now `P2`, but `[[Prototype]]` of `obj` is still `P1`.

Note that it is *only* functions that have a `prototype` property. Note also that the `prototype` property of a function is not the same as the `[[Prototype]]` property of the function!

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. thanks for the very clear answer! i had 'figured' all of these, but hadn't fleshed it out so exactly.

Comment: That was a great answer and helped me understand inheritance although it does say on the mozilla site that the __proto__ property can be changed to point to a different object after initial construction. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: something to add: i believe in Firefox you can access `[[Prototype]]` as `__proto__`

Answer (score 12):

To answer your question directly: logically it is an object's private copy of the `prototype` property of its constructor. Using metalanguage this is how objects are created:

```
// not real JS

var Ctr = function(...){...};
Ctr.prototype = {...}; // some object with methods and properties

// the object creation sequence: var x = new Ctr(a, b, c);
var x = {};
x["[[prototype]]"] = Ctr.prototype;
var result = Ctr.call(x, a, b, c);
if(typeof result == "object"){ x = result; }
// our x is fully constructed and initialized at this point
```

At this point we can modify the prototype, and the change will be reflected by all objects of the class, because they refer to the prototype by reference:

```
Ctr.prototype.log = function(){ console.log("...logging..."); };

x.log();  // ...logging..
```

But if we change the prototype on the constructor, already created objects will continue referring to the old object:

```
Ctr.prototype = {life: 42};
// let's assume that the old prototype didn't define "life"

console.log(x.life);  // undefined
x.log();              // ...logging...
```

In the full accordance with the standard `[[prototype]]` is not available, but Mozilla extends the standard with `__proto__` property (read-only), which is exposing the normally hidden `[[prototype]]`:

- [the Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Property_Inheritance_Revisited/Determining_Instance_Relationships)
- [overview of Mozilla's extensions: __count__, __proto__, __parent__](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/02/26/javascript-magic-properties-using-count-proto-and-parent.aspx)

Again, `__proto__` can be legalized in [the next ES3.1 standard](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=es3.1:es3.1_proposal_working_draft).

Comment: Hmm.. instead of standardizing __proto__, they created Object.getPrototypeOf(target), which will return target.[[Prototype]]. The main difference is that you can't assign to the result.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to olavk's answer: Some JavaScript implementations (eg [mozilla's](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)) allow to access the [[Prototype]] property directly...