# Clarification: Javascript prototype update confusion

Tags: javascript, prototype

[Possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391550/javascript-prototypal-inheritance-doubt-ii), but answer shows what's observed but doesn't explain why it happens that way.

Let's create three function constructors.

```
function A() {
}

function B() {
}

function C() {
}
C.prototype.nm = "C";
B.prototype = new A()
var obj = new B()
B.prototype = new C()
console.log(obj.nm); // prints, undefined.
```

So after the last line I was expecting 'obj' to receive properties from prototype of C but it's not. So does it mean that once the object is created it is tied to whatever prototype it was assigned during creation ? Why is it that way, I mean I can receive live updates to object through the prototype but wouldn't it be better if can get updates from multiple objects just changing constructors prototype property ?

Comment: "wouldn't it be better if can get updates from multiple objects just changing constructors prototype property" --- nope, it wouldn't be.

Comment: @zerkms, so once the object is created, it is tied to a particular prototype and will only receive updates from that prototype and nothing else.

Comment: and that's great. It's how predictable code should behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean that once the object is created it is tied to whatever
>   prototype it was assigned during creation ?

Yes, exactly. Objects inherit properties from the object in their [[Prototype]] internal property.

That property is set when you create the instance:

> [**13.2.2 [[Construct]]**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)
>
> - Let *proto* be the value of calling the [[Get]] internal property of *F* with argument `"prototype"`.
> - If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*proto*) is Object, set the [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to *proto*.

But if you change the `prototype` property of a constructor, it won't affect previous instances.

In fact, `prototype` is not special by itself, it's just that [[Construct]] internal method uses it while creating instances.

> once the object is created it is tied to whatever prototype it was
>   assigned during creation ?

Mostly yes. You can change it, but is not recommended (because of performance issues), using:

- `__proto__`: this was a non-standard property in `Object.prototype` which could be used as a getter or setter of [[Prototype]]. ECMAScript 6 [standardized it](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__) in Annex B (Additional ECMAScript Features for Web Browsers).
- [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.setprototypeof), a new method introduced by ECMAScript 6.

Comment: Yeah, tested it. '__proto__' can be used to change the prototype of a object to something else. But it is changing the 'constructor' property. That's strange.

Answer (score 0):

You do not assign B any specific prototype properties so the inheritance chain is broken.