# javascript prototyping: why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at trying the following code:

```
var classA = function() {};
classA.prototype = { x: 4, y: 6 };
classA.prototype.prototype = { z: 10 };
var foo = new classA();
alert(foo.z);
```

Why does the alert come back as undefined?  Shouldn't javascript follow the prototype chain to find z?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383201/relation-between-prototype-and-prototype-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default an `object prototype` is an empty object.

```
classA.prototype = { x: 4, y: 6 };
classA.prototype.prototype = { z: 10 };
```

is equivalent to

```
classA.prototype = { x: 4, y: 6, prototype: { z: 10 }};
```

you just added a property named `prototype` to `classA`

`z` is a property of the object `prototype` belonging to `classA`

`alert(foo.prototype.z);` will work

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that you can change the prototype of a prototype or if such a thing even exists.  Do this instead

```
var classA = function() {};
classA.prototype = { x: 4, y: 6 };
classA.prototype.z = 10;
var foo = new classA();
alert(foo.z);
```

Answer (score 1):

The prototype of an object is stored in `__proto__`. The `prototype` property on a class is actually the default prototype for its instances. I found [this article](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/) to be very helpful.

If you change your code to use `__proto__` for the prototype of the prototype, it will behave as you expected.

```
var classA = function() {};
classA.prototype = { x: 4, y: 6 };
classA.prototype.__proto__ = { z: 10 };
var foo = new classA();
alert(foo.z);
```

Comment: Except that `__proto__` is non-standard

Answer (score 1):

The prototype property comes for free on all functions - in case the function is intended to be used as a constructor (it defines the prototype to be assigned to instances created by that constructor).

You are trying to assign a prototype property to a non-function - which is meaningless. In some browsers The prototype of an object can be get and set by the non standard **proto** attribute.

There is also a new ECMA standard API for accessing an object's prototype

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)
```

but it is not yet supported by all browsers

Edit: just realized I am the author of Austin's link :-)