# Constructors and prototype properties in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm figuring out prototypes in JS, and I can't figure for the life of me why this doesn't work:

```
var Mammal = {
    legs: 4
}

function Dog(color, soundItMakes) {
    this.prototype = Mammal;
    this.color = color;
    this.soundItMakes = soundItMakes;
    this.woof = function() { return this.soundItMakes; }
}

aDog = new Dog("brown", "beep beep!");
document.write(Mammal.legs + "<br>");
document.write(aDog.color + "<br>" + aDog.woof() + "<br>" + aDog.legs);
```

The first `document.write()` returns 4 as would be expected, but the second returns undefined for aDog.legs. Any advice would be a huge help.

Comment: I recommend to read [MDN - Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Relation between \[\[Prototype\]\] and prototype in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383201/1529630)

Comment: Sorry, added clarification of what was returning undefined

Comment: There's nothing special about a `.prototype` property on a plain object. Only on functions. The way you have it right now, you'd have to do `aDog.prototype.legs`, which wouldn't be very desirable.

Comment: Maybe the following answer can help explaining what prototype is and how it's used. As mentioned before; prototype only does something if you set it's value on a constructor function (normal function used to construct instances). There are other ways to create instances and set it's prototype chain like Object.create. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now `prototype` is the own property of the `Dog` instance object. So if you want you could access it like `aDog.prototype.legs`. However, this is not the same as setting `Dog` *constructor prototype*.

Your code should be this:

```
var Mammal = {
    legs: 4
}

function Dog(color, soundItMakes) {
    this.color = color;
    this.soundItMakes = soundItMakes;
    this.woof = function() { return this.soundItMakes; }
}

Dog.prototype = Mammal;
```

Comment: I see what you mean about Mammal being the prototype of the INSTANCE of Dog, but I still don't quite understand why that should prevent the instance from having access to a property of its prototype...

Comment: @somecbusnerd: Because having a `.prototype` property doesn't mean an object inherits from that.

Comment: @somecbusnerd: You have to understand that prototype is a special object member that is applied to the "class", and not any specific instance.  In your original example, try accessing the legs member via aDog.prototype.legs and you should see the correct result.  This is because "prototype" is treated as any other member variable when assigned to an instance.  Only when assigned to a class (i.e. Dog.prototype = Mammal) will it utilize the special inheritance behavior.