# Universal Method Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

I want to create a method in javascript which can be used by every object which is an element. no need to add the method like

```
object = {
 methodName : function(){

 }
};
```

Comment: Extend `Object` prototype, maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript add prototype method to all functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126844/javascript-add-prototype-method-to-all-functions)

Comment: Also see [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to extend `Object` prototype.

```js
// extend
Object.prototype.myFunction = function(){
   console.log('universal Object function');
}
// now every object created and instance of Object will have the method myFunction available to use.
var a = {};
a.myFunction();
```

Please, bear in mind this [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

Comment: If you're going to extend `Object.property` you should at least do it with `Object.defineProperty()` and make sure the new property is not enumerable.