# Difference between defining classes in different ways in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between defining classed in the following ways?

1)

```
var parentCls = {
    name:'John',
    callMe : function (){
        alert('Method gets called');
    }
}
parentCls.callMe();
```

2)

```
function parentCls(){
    this.name='John';
    this.callMe = function (){
        alert('Method gets called');
    }
}
parentCls.CallMe()
```

Thanks

Comment: Thansk for the link! So now my question is also what is the difference between :1)var functionOne = function() {
    // Some code
};
2)
var functionOne = {
    // Some code
};

Comment: Second is not a function, but an object

Comment: Your second snippet is an error.

Comment: It's a bit misleading to talk about "classes" in JavaScript (even though ES6 will finally use the `class` keyword). JavaScript has objects and constructor functions, which create objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an object:

```
var parentCls = {
    name:'John',
    callMe : function (){
        alert('Method gets called');
    }
}
parentCls.callMe();
```

This is a function:

```
function parentCls(){
    this.name='John';
    this.callMe = function (){
        alert('Method gets called');
    }
}
parentCls.callMe()
```

In this code, you will receive an error. You can't access `parentCls.callMe()`

More here:
[javascript : function and object...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958417/javascript-function-and-object)

Comment: sorry I forgot to add: var obj = new parentCls();
obj.callMe(); So why this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMfcsYzj-9M) at 13:20 says AnswerPrototype is a class? Is it a typo?

Comment: It's not a typo, a class is practically an object.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use `function parentCls()` **if you have something to pass to it.** For example

```
function parentCls(name){
    this.name=name;
    this.callMe = function (){
        alert('Method gets called');
    }
}
```

So you can create an object like `var newObject = new parentCls('abc');`