# is function an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is function a 'Function' object in JavaScript? if so, when I create a constructor function like:

```
//this is a constructor function

function foo(){
    this.name="xx";
}
```

Does foo has a property named **proto** pointing to the Function's prototype? How can I see this property?

ps: If **proto** is created when an instance is created via the `new` keyword, why does not `function foo` have it? According to above, `foo` is created via `new Function`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript : function and object...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958417/javascript-function-and-object)

Comment: I think there are two different question~~

Comment: consider that `String.slice` is undefined, but `String.prototype.slice` is the same exact same function as `"".slice()` and is also the same function as `new String("hello").constructor.prototype.slice`. it is a little funny at first, but the "new " operator essentially puts anything the constructor's prototype defines into virtual properties on the resulting instance.

Comment: someone should mention that from a performance standpoint, it's not a great idea to modify the proto after you have existing instances, so these shortcuts like `__proto__` and `.constructor.prototype` are of limited utility in efficiently-written applications.

Comment: @dandavis: *"someone should mention that from a performance standpoint, it's not a great idea to modify the proto after you have existing instances"* What do you mean by "modify the proto"? *Modifying* it (adding properties, etc.) or *replacing* it? (Separately, note that assigning a new value to `obj.constructor.prototype` will have no effect on `obj` at all; but it will change what happens the next time that constructor function is used...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: i'm referring to the (first) scary red box here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto, but i had V8 in mind...

Comment: @dandavis: Okay, that would be *replacing* an object's prototype, and would relate only to `.__proto__` (replacing `.constructor.prototype` has no effect on the object). It's also flatly wrong when it says "**every** browser" (their emph). :-) While it impacts Firefox's engine, there's no effect on V8 or JScript: [test](http://jsperf.com/impact-of-replacing-prototype). (*Modifying* the prototype doesn't have any negative perf impact either -- [test](http://jsperf.com/impact-of-modifying-prototype) --but that's different.) MDN is community-edited, and so sometimes wrong, 'till it's fixed. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: good info. my concern was more the actual de-optimizing cost of object unboxing from redefining the object, but on a small number of instances of small objects, that's going to be negligible. Additionally, that cost might be smaller with setting a proto than touching each object would be (that's the idea), especially since prototype typically contains functions, not optimize-able data.  once configured, the instance property access times should be about the same as before (except perhaps in FF). i could have been more clear, but you raise a good point.

Comment: @dandavis: Not quite following you. If you have time, perhaps you could demonstrate what concerns you? I'm not seeing an issue, the main thing is to avoid `delete`. I'm always keen to know more about JS performance...

Answer (score 1):

> is function a object in javascript?

Yes.

> Does foo has a property named proto pointing to the Function 's prototype?

Not named `proto`, no. This is a bit of a confusing area:

- All objects have an underlying prototype object they inherit from. From ES5 onward, you can get a reference to that object via `Object.getPrototypeOf` (e.g., `var p = Object.getPrototypeOf(blah)` gives you a reference to `blah`'s prototype). *Some* engines (including Firefox's SpiderMonkey) also make underlying prototype available via the pseudo-property `__proto__`, and that will be [in the spec as of ES6](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__), but officially [only when JavaScript is used in browsers](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-additional-built-in-properties).
- *Separately*, all normal functions have a property called `prototype`, which is **not** that function's underyling prototype (see above). Instead, it's the object that will get assigned as the underlying prototype of objects *created* using that function as a constructor via the `new` keyword.

Since this is a bit confusing, let's draw a picture. Suppose we have this code:

```
function Foo() {
    this.name = "xx";
}

var f = new Foo();
```

*(Since I used it as a constructor, I've used the name `Foo` rather than `foo` to stick to conventions.)*

Here's what we now have in memory:

```
+------------+
|  Function  |
| (function) |
+------------+       +-----------+
| __proto__  |----+->| (object)  | This is the object assigned to functions
| prototype  |----/  +-----------+ as their underyling prototype
+------------+    |  | call      |
                  |  | apply     |
                  |  | bind      |
                  |  | ...       |
                  |  +-----------+
+------------+    |
|     Foo    |    |
| (function) |    |
+------------+    |
| __proto__  |----+
|            |          +----------+
| prototype  |----+---->| (object) | This is the object assigned to
+------------+    |     +----------+ objects created via `new Foo`
                  |     | (blank)  |
                  |     +----------+
+-----------+     |
|     f     |     |
| (object)  |     |
+-----------+     |
| __proto__ |-----+
| name: xx  |
+-----------+
```

(I've left off the references to `Object.property` above to keep things simpler.)

> How can I see this property.

See above, either `__proto__` (on only some engines for now, will be standard in ES6) or via `Object.getPrototypeOf` (ES5).

Example:

```js
// Shows you the object referenced by Function.prototype,
// which is `foo`'s underyling prototype
// ONLY WORKS ON SOME ENGINES for now (including Firefox's SpiderMonkey)
console.log(foo.__proto__);

// Shows you the object referenced by foo.prototype
console.log(foo.prototype);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your answer, you mention that the underlying prototype of objects is created via new foo. But the function foo is created by using new Function(). why does foo not have the underlying prototype?

Comment: @monokeros: It does, its underlying prototype is the object that `Function.prototype` points to. I've added a diagram to the answer to help clarify, and expanded on `__proto__` vs. `prototype`.

Comment: "*…`__proto__` … will be standard as of ES6*" deserves some qualification. `__proto__` is included in the ES 6 Draft **for browsers only**, probably only because it has been implemented in some browsers. Mozilla invented it, deprecated it, now [*tolerates it under sufferance*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). [*Object.getPrototypeOf*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.getprototypeof) is the recommended method that persists in ES 6. Your answer suggests that it is ES5 only and not in ES 6.

Comment: @RobG: I don't think my previous wording suggested `getPrototypeOf` was going away, but I've reworded anyway. Hopefully no ambiguity now.

Comment: @RobG: Re browsers only: Holy \*\*\*\*. I hadn't seen that change.

Comment: yeah, but V8 is probably a browser core implementation... (nodejs should be fine, and what else is there really?)

Comment: @dandavis: V8 is *used* in some browsers, but it's not just a browser engine. In theory, they could disable `__proto__` outside the browser environment... (But it's there in Node.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your answer. It's clear to understand it ~