# How do custom objects inherit from Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

How does a custom created object have access to methods such as `.toString()`
method which is an Object method. How is a custom class linked to an Object

[This](http://helephant.com/2009/08/17/javascript-prototype-chaining/) article states

> All objects ultimately have the Object constructor at the end of their
>   prototype chain. This means any methods or properties added to the
>   Object property are automatically available to all objects.
>
> In the previous example, if we called rufus.toString(), javascript
>   would check the rufus object, then the Cat object, then the Pet
>   object. The Pet object’s prototype was created with the Object
>   constructor (using the object literal shortcut) so javascript would
>   then find the toString() method on the Object’s prototype

Now after reading through the article I understand that in order to inherit from an object we have to specify in the prototype of the function constructor of an object the object we would like to inherit from. Now I read that by default the prototype property is empty.Then how can an object have the property toString() ? I dont understand the statement

> The Pet object’s prototype was created with the Object constructor
>   (using the object literal shortcut)

**Update:**

I read that the prototype property of the constructor function is empty by default. I read that [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-prototype-in-plain-detailed-language/) I have pasted the quote here

> First, every JavaScript function has a prototype property (this
>   property is empty by default), and you attach properties and methods
>   on this prototype property when you want to implement inheritance.

How do we inherit from the javascript Object then ?

Comment: *Now I read that by default the prototype property is empty.* Where did you read that? Note that the prototype of an object is **not** the same as the prototype property (usually associated with a constructor).

Comment: @torazaburo could you explain that a little bit. Could you explain the difference between protoype of an object and the prototype property ? I thinking i am mixing them ..

Comment: Yes, I too think you are. There are better explanations out on the web than I could give in a paragraph. Search for "difference between prototype and `__proto__`" or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All objects inherit the properties of `Object` via prototypal inheritance. If you do :

```
var b = {};
console.log(b.__proto__)
```

you can see all the properties inherited from `Object`.

So, what happens is that when you do `b.toString()`, it will look for the `toString()` function on `b`, then it will keep going up the prototype chain and ultimately reach `Object` which has this function.

**EDIT:**

**Function Constructors vs Objects:**

Just to clarify, a function constructor defined like:

```
var a = function() {
   this.b = "b";
   this.c = "c";
}
```

has its prototype set to `function`. This can be verified by doing `console.log(a)`.

However, we use `a` to create new *Objects* like this:

```
var d = new a();
```

And these objects have their prototype set to `Object` which, again, can be verified by doing `console.log(d)`.

More details [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958417/javascript-function-and-object)

Comment: I read that the __proto__ property is a reference to the prototype property and by default the prototype property is empty unless explicitly specified. How can a custom object implicitly inherit from `Object` then ?

Comment: Where did you read this? For a detailed understanding refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: prototype property for a constructor function, not an object. Those are two separate things.

Comment: Could you post a link that explains the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

Referring from JavaScript The Definitive Guide:

> All objects created by object literals i.e `{}` have the same prototype object, and we can refer to this prototype object in JavaScript code as `Object.prototype`. Objects created using the `new` keyword and a constructor invocation use the value of the `prototype` property of the constructor function as their prototype. So the object created by `new Object()` inherits from `Object.prototype` just as the object created by `{}` does. Similarly, the object created by `new Array()` uses `Array.prototype` as its prototype, and the object created by `new Date()` uses `Date.prototype` as its prototype.

So all objects which are created using `{}` literals will have `Object.prototype` as their prototype and have access to methods defined by `Object.prototype` for example `toString()` etc etc.

The `new` operator is used to create and initialize new objects. The `new` keyword must be used with a function invocation. When a function invocation is used with `new` keyword it is called constructor invocation.

Objects created with `new` and function invocation will inherit from the `prototype` property of constructors. So objects created with `new Date()` will inherit from `Date.prototype` and objects created with `new Array()` will inherit from `Array.prototype`.

You can change this `prototype` property to make objects inherit from your own custom objects. For example

```
function myFunction() {
    this.name = 'a';
    this.age = 20;
}

myFunction.prototype = {
    toString: function() {
        // you can override default toString() method here..
    },

    // you can define as many functions here as you want.
};

var myObj = new myFunction();
```

Object `myObj` will inherit from `myFunction.prototype` and all methods defined in this objects will be available to `myObj`.

EcmaScript5 defines a new method `Object.create()` for creating objects have prototype other than `Object.prototype`. For example

```
var prototypeObject = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
var obj1 = Object.create(prototypeObject);
```

Now `obj1' will inherit from`prototypeObject' and not from `Object.prototype`

Answer (score 0):

You asked

> How does a custom created object have access to methods such as
>   .toString() method which is an Object method. How is a custom class
>   linked to an Object

From reading what you posted you seemed by have over thunk it. You got it, then you *ungot* it.  To answer the question without including any code.

In programming, all objects inherit from a default object. Think of this as *JavaScripts template*, it has to start with something and it has base properties and methods and you build on top of that. Each object has different base properties.  *I stated in a prior post that the prototype chain ends here, but that is not entirely accurate, as the prototype chain end in null.*