# If functions are objects in JavaScript, then why can't they have name-value pair syntax for their properties?

Tags: javascript

If functions are objects in javascript, then why can't they have name-value pair syntax for their properties? For example, why is the following not possible/allowed?

```
function xx() {
    name: 'jhg'
}
alert(xx.name);
```

and vice versa:

```
var person = {
    this.age = 32;
};
alert(person.age);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript : function and object...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958417/javascript-function-and-object)

Answer (score 3):

You could assign the properties, you want, but not [`Function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), which is a read only property with the name of the function.

```js
function xx() { }

xx.name = 'jhg'; // is read only, because it's the function's name
xx.foo = 'bar';

console.log(xx.name);
console.log(xx.foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because function declarations aren't object initializers. They're just different syntaxes, for different purposes, with different use cases and design criteria. Arrays are also objects, but we use a different initializer notation for them, too. Same with regular expressions.

(Note that your first example is perfectly valid and will run; `name` is a label, not a property name, and labels an *ExpressionStatement* that isn't used for anything.)

(Also note that functions do, as of ES2015, have a built-in `name` property. That's just not how you initialize it. [That function's name will be `"xx"` in your example.])

Comment: @user8783104: Tried running *what*, and "it didn't work" *how*? :-)

Answer (score 0):

They are objects, but they are not object literals.

A function can be used to create an instance of an object. For example:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log('Hi, my name is ' + this.name);
    };
}

var bob = new Person('Bob', 24);
```

The `bob` variable is an instance of the `Person` function.
You can access the properties from `bob` like this:

```
console.log( bob.name ) // "Bob"
```

You could also define it literally, like this:

```
var bob = {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 24
};
```

The `function` syntax is used to create functions. They are templates that can be used over and over again. The *object literal* syntax is used when you only want one instance, or also for data, without any behavior attached to it.