# Cast an Object to another Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, casting

I have an Animal Object that looks like this:

```
AnimalObject {attributes: {…}, locations: {…}}
```

Animal Object Class:

```
export default class AnimalObject {
  constructor(apiResult, included) {
    this.attributes = apiResult.attributes;
    this.locations = apiResult.locations;

    ...
  }
```

I now have a specific AnimalObject called FishObject that has some fish related methods.

```
export default class FishObject extends AnimalObject {

  getFood(){
   const foods = this.getFishFood(this.attributes)
   return foods
  }

  talk(){
    return "blub"
  }
}
```

Is there a way in javascript that I can cast a list of Animal Objects `[{AnimalObject}, {AnimalObject}]` into Fish objects? I want to map through the AnimalObject list and call a fish method.

--Update: I'm most likely going to instantiate with the Fish class...

Comment: Looks like a code smell and that those objects should have been `FishObject` to begin with.

Comment: (A class _is an object_) --- Also may you explain what you mean by cast?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it allows you to change the object type. It's used in Java

Comment: @Joseph hmm.. ok point taken

Comment: @lost9123193 I'm confused. JavaScript isn't Java. Have you seen something to say that casting is possible in JavaScript?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, a `class` is not an Object, it's actually a constructor function sugar syntax. An Object is created from a constructor or class after `new` is called on it. OP probably just wants to do like: `const fishObj = new AnimalObject(argsHere), dogObj = new AnimalObject; /* without args you don't need parameter when new */`. The point of a generic `class AnimalObject` should be reuse for multiple animal types.

Comment: @evolutionxbox `class Test{ constructor(){ this.test = 'worked'; } }; console.log(typeof Test);`. Hope you learned something.

Comment: `function`s have a `prototype` property that is an Object, but the `function` is still just a `function`... calling `new` creates an Object out of the `function` as long as it has `this` references. @evolutionxbox, it will help the OP and yourself to know how it works. I even have books that teach incorrectly, so don't feel bad.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, that's great. Let's not call construtors or classes Objects then. It will confuse OP.

Comment: @StackSlave No. I'm have deleted my comments. btw - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958417/javascript-function-and-object

Answer (score 0):

you can handle this with the `Object.assign()` method.
If you wrap it like below :

```
function castToFish(animalObject) {
     return Object.assign(new FishObject(),  animalObject)
}
```

Then you can transform your array with `map` :

```
var fishArray = [...someAnimalObjects].map(castToFish)
```

Of course, I assumed that you can use es6 syntax.