# Everything in Javascript is a Function

Tags: javascript

In the past I've been told: "Everything in Javascript is a Function". I'm curious how much truth there is to this. As an example I quote the Chrome JS Console:

```
> String
function String() { [native code] }
> Number
function Number() { [native code] }
> Object
function Object() { [native code] }
> Array
function Array() { [native code] }
> Function
function Function() { [native code] }
```

What about literals, operators?

Comment: The things you list are functions, but not everything.  I've never heard anyone say that about JavaScript personally.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449596/every-object-is-a-function-and-every-function-is-object-which-is-correct

Comment: "Literal" refers to how certain values are represented in the source code and the parser knows how to interpret it. At this level, the concept of a function does not even exist. You are comparing apples with oranges in this point. Not sure what to say about "operators"... they are a different beast altogether and it does not make sense to include them in this comparison either.

Comment: The things you list are all constructor functions. That is Javascript's way of defining a class (or something like a class). It does not mean that the objects (instances) constructed are themselves functions. E.g. in `var s = new String()`, `s` is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Everything in Javascript is a Function"

Citation needed.

Your proof there actually proves that constructors are functions.  And a constructor is the handle for the closest thing JavaScript has to a class.

Try this:

```
> typeof String
"function"

> var a = new String("testing123");
> typeof a
"object"
```

But really, functions are just a special kind of object.

So I would revise your statement to say instead:

> *Nearly* everything in Javascript is an object, including functions

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I don't have a citation to my quote, it's just something that I seemed to remember someone saying, clearly it was wrong.

Comment: Instead of saying "Nearly everything in Javascript is an object, including functions", it's better to be more specific and say "Everything that is not a *primitive* is an object.", and this includes functions. Note that `typeof` is not always reliable, as `typeof null` is `"object"`, but in actual fact, it's a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about a function, but I've always heard everything in JavaScript is an object.

Comment: [(Not) Everything in JavaScript is an Object](http://blog.brew.com.hk/not-everything-in-javascript-is-an-object/). A function is an object in JavaScript.