# How to invoke a function, as a "new Object", and call as a function again?

Tags: javascript, oop

As a learning experience, I'm trying to make my own little console debug script that is object-oriented. I want it to be similar to jQuery in that you can **call it as a function** (`jQuery('div')`) **or as an object** (`jQuery.ajax()`).

I have the code below which is almost working. It is basically an alias of "console.log".

My goal is to be able to perform the following:

```
var log = new RadDebug;
// Create our function

log('You selected: %s', fruit_type);
// Invoke the top-level function
// Output: You selected: "Apple"

log.warn('You selected: %s', fruit_type);
// Invoke a method "warn", which displays a caution icon next to the log.
// Output: (!) You selected "Apple"
```

---

The script I am working on:

```
function RadDebug() {
  var debug_enabled = (debug_mode && window.console && window.console.log instanceof Function);

  // If this object was already initialize, redirect the function call to the ".log()" as default
  if ( this.initialized ) {
    return this.log.apply( this, arguments );
  }
  this.initialized = true;

  this.log = function() {
    if ( !debug_enabled ) return;
    console.log.apply( console, arguments );
  };

  this.info = function() {
    if ( !debug_enabled ) return;
    console.info.apply( console, arguments );
  };

  // More methods below
}
```

---

### The problem:

Calling `log.warn("hello world")` works as you would expect.

Calling `log("hello world")` tells me that `TypeError: Object is not a function`.

**Question:** How do I get it to work as a function *and* having object-like properties? (Like how jQuery does it)

*(This question has been resolved thanks to @FelixKling. The final code is [available as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/RadGH/408fe3c45dc8ce835bf1) if you want to check it out).*

Comment: Every function is also an object in JavaScript, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449596/every-object-is-a-function-and-every-function-is-object-which-is-correct

Comment: I'm aware of this, but the issue is that `log()` is no longer usable as a function - *only* as an object (such as `log.info()`). It's the one thing I'm not able to figure out for this mini-project.

Comment: ^ Don't use `RadDebug` as constructor function, just attach the methods to the function itself.

Comment: @FelixKling I tried that, `var log = function() {...}`. It resolves the `log()` issue. But then I cannot use `log.info()`. I'd like to have "the best of both worlds".

Comment: I think you missed the second part of what @Felix Kling mentioned, "just attach the methods to the function itself"

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought of that, I'll play with it. He also posted an answer that I'll check out. Thanks guys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `RadDebug` as constructor function, just attach the methods to the function itself.

For example:

```
var RadDebug = (function() {
  // Some IIFE to keep debug_enabled and functions local
  var debug_enabled = (debug_mode && window.console && window.console.log instanceof Function);

  // Functions here
  function log() {
    if ( !debug_enabled ) return;
    console.log.apply( console, arguments );
  }

  function info() {
    if ( !debug_enabled ) return;
    console.info.apply( console, arguments );
  }

  // ...

  // Attach methods to "main" log function
  log.log = log;
  log.info = info;
  // ...

  // Return log function (RadDebug === log)
  return log;
}());
```

Then you use it as

```
RadDebug('You selected: %s', fruit_type);
// same as
RadDebug.log('You selected: %s', fruit_type);

RadDebug.info('You selected: %s', fruit_type);
```

or alias `RadDebug` to whatever you want (e.g. `log`).

Comment: Yes this is it! Very interesting way to do it. It'll take a bit more time to soak in how this all works but it seems pretty slick. The anonymous function is building the "log" function and attaching the methods to it. Seems very clean that way. Thank you!

Comment: This is just an excellent answer. It explains so much about the way to approach javascript. I wish i could vote more.

Answer (score 2):

Functions are Objects in Javascript. You can return a function in your `RadDebug` function and set one of its members to the same returned function. For example:

```
var hello = function () {
  var fn = function () {
    console.log("Hello");
  }

  fn.hello = fn;

  return fn;
}

var sayHello = new hello();
sayHello(); // prints "Hello"
sayHello.hello(); // prints "Hello"
```