# why 'function type' can apply to '{} type'

Tags: javascript, typescript

Look at the code below, with no errors, I want to know why `function type` can apply to `{} type`

`"typescript": "~2.9.1"`,

```
interface IIndexCtlState {
    x: {}
}
const state: IIndexCtlState = {
    x: function y() {return "sdf"}
}
```

Comment: I don't know about typescript, but in javascript, (almost) everything is an object, including functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing in typescript is structural, `{}` defines a type with no members. Any other type can be compatible with this type. Primitives, functions, other objects, anything:

```
let s: {};
s = 1;
s = ""
s = () => ""
s = null // err under strictNullChecks
```

Under strict null checks, `null` and `undefined` are not assignable to `{}`. But other than that anything can be assigned to `{}`.

If you want to represent something that is an  object the `object` type might be better but functions are still allowed (since functions are objects)

```
let s: object;
s = 1; //err
s = "" // err
s = () => ""
s = { foo: ""};
s = null // err under strictNullChecks
```

Answer (score 0):

"I don't know about typescript, but in javascript, (almost) everything is an object, including functions – Jaromanda X 10 mins ago
"
Nope it's the exacte opposite, everything is a Function in JavaScript, meaning Objects are Functions so are primary values. for example Object extends(inherit) Function and not the opposite.

Comment: This question was not about `Object` constructor, but about object type `{}` which is not a function. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449596/every-object-is-a-function-and-every-function-is-object-which-is-correct