# What is the type of a function that also has other properties?

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling to write the type for the function `foo` as below:

```
function foo() { do something }
foo.boo = () => { do something else }

foo("hello");
foo.boo("hello");
```

The code works in JavaScript, so it is possible to do that. But then what would be the type of `foo`?

Comment: functions are objects in JavaScript.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures

Comment: What would be the type of foo?  ->  `type Foo = { boo: () => void;  (): void; };  const fooTest:Foo = foo; //<--valid`

Comment: Salman A,  Check this: ```const funcExample = () => {};  console.log(typeof funcExample === 'object') //false```

Comment: @NikolaiKushpela typeof reports `"function"` for callable objects. (() => {}) instanceof Object` is `true`. Also see [Every Object is a function and every function is Object - Which is Correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3449596). [From the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-objects): "*an object is a member of the built-in type Object; and a function is a callable object*". Also [defines the function](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-function) as "*member of the Object type that may be invoked as a subroutine*"

Comment: @NikolaiKushpela   But technically there still objects, there known as Function object.   It's this feature of Javascript that allows functions to be first-class objects and allows you to pass them about as if there just objects.

Comment: @NikolaiKushpela also, have a look at [the spec of `typeof`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation): note that in step 11 it asserts the value is an object. Then *if callable* reports `"function"`, otherwise it reports `"object"`.

Comment: Does [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKb5ym) fully adress the question? If so, then I or someone (maybe @Keith?) will write up an answer explaining or find a valid duplicate target. If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

In the end I've found the answer by using the Typescript Playground:

```
interface Foo {
    (x: string): void;
    boo(x: string): void;
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: Apart from using an `interface`, how is this different to what I posted in comments?

Comment: Yeah this is just my playground link from the comments without attribution.  Please either remove this answer or edit it so as not to plagiarize, and if you do edit it, consider providing some sort of explanation so that it’s not a code-only answer. Even better would be for you to remove it and then let @Keith write an answer, but that’s up to you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I think you are talking about `methods` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp

You can return anything you want from Typescript, just like Javascript, if you want to type the return of the function is quite simple.

```js
// named functions
function myFunction(): { myMethod: () => number } { 
  return { myFunction: () => 10 };
}

// anonymous arrow function
const myFunction = (): { myMethod: () => void } => {
  return { myMethod: () => { return; } };
}
```

I think this is enough for this question in particular.

These goes deeper on functions: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html

---

Just like a particular remark, You can opt for strictly type returns or just infer functions, I often do not strictly type function returns, but that is a  personal preference.